# Benchmarking TCP Server

Tags: tcp, benchmark

I've written a very basic TCP-Server based on libevent. Now I would like to test the Server.

Is there a tool which generates a lot of connections so that I can check how much concurrent connections the server can handle?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I'd use [iperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/) for something like this. On ArchLinux's repositories, I found tcpperf, which seems to originate from [here](http://www.wand.net.nz/~stj2/nsc/software.html) -- looks a bit dated, YMMV.

Comment: https://github.com/esnet/iperf/wiki/IperfProtocolSpecification